# problems when starting ubuntu 20.04 on the kernel 5.4.0-48-generic

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

Today the kernel on Ubuntu 20.04 was updated to 5.4.0-48-generic and my computer stopped booting. On 5.4.0-47-generic, the download goes without problems. Tried installing Nvidia 450.66 drivers but didn't help. On the desktop, gnm3 does not load at all, and on the desktop, lghtdm displays the following message "/ dev / mapper / vg ubuntu-root: clean xxx / xxx blocks".

Comment: Please use [su] or [ubuntu.se] for this type of questions. This site here is for programming problems.